# How to pass filter parameters in <sp-widget> service portal

Tags: angularjs, servicenow

I have one out of the box widget it contains a table.This has a filter parameter by default like this

`request.requested_forDYNAMIC90d1921e5f510100a9ad2572f2b477fe^ORrequest.opened_byDYNAMIC90d1921e5f510100a9ad2572f2b477fe^request.stateIN-7,-6,-5,1,2^request.active=true^EQ`

It works fine.

Now am calling the same widget in some other page using a following format

server script:

```
`data.widgetName= $sp.getWidget("data-definition",'');`
```

html code:

```
<sp-widget widget='data.widgetName'></sp-widget>
```

Now I need to pass these parameters to this widget 
`request.requested_forDYNAMIC90d1921e5f510100a9ad2572f2b477fe^ORrequest.opened_byDYNAMIC90d1921e5f510100a9ad2572f2b477fe^request.stateIN-7,-6,-5,1,2^request.active=true^EQ`

How can pass it?

I have refered this link https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/kingston-servicenow-platform/page/build/service-portal/concept/c_NestedWidgets.html

Ho I couldn't understand how to pass it with keys?

Kindly anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

your approach is correct. You can call your widget with

```
data.widgetName = $sp.getWidget("widget", '');
```

The method *getWidget* has two parameters. First your desired widget and second the options. You just missed the options. 
Within your widget you can define such options.

Here is an example for a embedded data table:

**Server Code:**

```
var yourFilter = "active=true";
data.tableWidget = $sp.getWidget("data-table", options = yourFilter);
```

**HTML**

```
<sp-widget widget="data.tableWidget"></sp-widget>
```

If you want to take a deeper look in *how can I embed widgets* than visit the ServiceNow documentation:

**Embedded Widgets**

https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/kingston-servicenow-platform/page/build/service-portal/concept/c_NestedWidgets.html

**Creating options**

https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/istanbul-servicenow-platform/page/build/service-portal/concept/c_WidgetInstanceOptions.html

Cheers